# How can I pass functions using server-side variables from client to server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, lambda

I have an express server with socketio on node, and a client on localhost. As I've been trying to pass functions between them using `socket.emit`, I've noticed that I can't pass anonymous functions and bind them to my server's context (so that variables/statements are executed entirely on the server side).
What I *want* to happen is that `bar` will be logged on the server side.

Here's an example:

```js
//CLIENT SIDE
socket.emit('foo', () => console.log('bar'));
```

```js
//SERVER SIDE
socket.on('foo', f => f());
```

When I run this code, `bar` gets logged onto the client side, rather than the server side. I also tried the following:

```js
socket.on('foo', f => f.bind(this)());
socket.on('foo', f => {
 global['g'] = f; g();
};
```

But nothing seems to work. I even tried wrapping it in a secondary anonymous function with the same methods, but no luck. Thoughts??

Comment: see [Acknowledgements](https://socket.io/docs/v3/emitting-events/#acknowledgements), though don't confuse it with it passing the actual function's code which is triggered on the server it's not that, also don't forget to check the callback is a function with typeof else its trivial to crash a server by sending up a string/number etc

Comment: @LawrenceCherone the example above is more of a way to show the issue, but I believe this is more of a vanilla JS question. I need that function, whatever it may be, to be run on the server side instead of simply triggered there. And thanks for the typeof remark, I totally forgot!